# Distorted views in interface builder. How is it possible?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

Just saw this in an itnerface builder file. How can this be done? Is this some super secret hidden feature of interface builder?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the "Bump Distortion" content filter. See the View Effects panel in IB (furthest right, looks like a stack of layers):

[image]